# Code Not Printing the Set When Map() is Used

Tags: python-3.x, string, palindrome

Q:1] Why are the print statements (commented) resulting in `print(mapped)` to not print the set? If those lines

```
# print(list(word))  
# print(list(palindrome))
```

are not-commented out, then the output results in:

['N', 'u', 'r', 's', 'e', 's', 'r', 'u', 'n']
['n', 'u', 'r', 's', 'e', 's', 'r', 'u', 'N']
`The zipped result is : set()`
Sentence is palindrome.

Q:2] Why does `N==n` not fail? I was expecting it to fail in the `for` loop.

```
def palindrome(word):
    if ' ' in word:
       word = word.replace(' ', '')
    palindrome = reversed(word)
    # print(list(word))
    # print(list(palindrome))
    mapped = zip(word, palindrome)
    # converting values to print as set 
    mapped = set(mapped) 
    # printing resultant values  
    print("The zipped result is : ",end="") 
    print(mapped) 
    for letter, rev_letter in zip(word, palindrome):
        if letter != rev_letter:
            return 'Not Palindrome'
    return 'Palindrome'

# Driver program to test sentencePalindrome() 
s = "Nurses run"
if (palindrome(s)): 
    print ("Sentence is palindrome.")
else: 
    print ("Sentence is not palindrome.")
```

If these lines below are commented

```
# print(list(word))
# print(list(palindrome))
```

the result is:
The zipped result is : {('u', 'u'), ('n', 'N'), ('s', 's'), ('N', 'n'), ('e', 'e'), ('r', 'r')}
Sentence is palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

## generators & containers

A generator resembles a sequence, as both are iterable.
But a generator offers its values just once,
while a container can be interrogated repeatedly.

You're getting hung up on that distinction,
and the trouble started in this line:

```
    palindrome = reversed(word)
```

You are thinking of it as, "Oh, I have a *word* I can view,
and each time I view it, it will be the same."
No. Sorry.
When you see it reported as something like:

```
<reversed object at 0x108ff7860>
```

you should think "generator" instead.

> Q1. After `print(list(palindrome))`, why is `mapped` the empty set?

Because `list()` exhausted the generator.
By the time `zip()` asked for the elements, all of them were already consumed.

> Q2. Why does the `for` loop never encounter `('N', 'n')` ?

Same answer.
The 2nd `zip` obtains zero items, as the 1st `zip` already drained them.

I can see why this "crazy" behavior may lead you to some confusion,
and a third question may already be on your lips:

> Q3. Why is `reversed()` lazy, why doesn't it just compute and store the whole result?

Well, in python-land, laziness is a virtue.
Consider this bit of code:

```
rev = reversed(very_long_sentence)
is_shouting = rev.startswith('!!')
```

Now `startswith()` only has to do a pair of character comparisons.
And `reversed()` doesn't even have to examine the entire very long string,
it can terminate early.
Allowing early termination is a Good Thing.
It can even let us operate on infinite generators,
knowing full well that due to a termination clause we won't ask for all possible values.

## fixing the bug

In your case, for this particular bit of code,
you plan to view the reversed word several times.
To handle that, a container is a much better fit for your needs.
Fortunately, it's simple to store all the generated items:

```
palindrome = ''.join(reversed(word))
```

This way, instead of a generator, you have a `str`.

Comment: I added the following print statements in the for loop. `print(letter)print(rev_letter)`. For `s=Nurses run`, only N and n were printed. When I tried `s=madam`, all characters were printer. Why?

Comment: You say you tried it twice: (1.) first and last letters were non-identical N/n, and (2.) first and last letters were identical m/m. You decided your function should offer an early exit for the first non-identical pair, returning a 'no' value. IDK, you tell me, why might the `print()` statements not have any effect subsequent to execution of a `return` statement?

Comment: word = word.replace(' ', '').lower() resolved the issue.